# check with vba rows in a table meeting a certain condition

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm just beginning in VBA and i have a table were i want to search for records meeting the condition: that a shipment is the same, enough stock and if this is true then i want to change per line the table_field complete_order to true.
I already changed the field complete_line to true if there was enough stock. But i can't get it for the total shipment. hopefully somebody can help me.

for changing the field complete_line i used this code and it functions well.:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM hal_b_prep")

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case.
Do Until rs.EOF = True
If rs!test.P <> "C" Then 'checking if shipment line is not completed yet
    If rs!SumOfav_stock > rs!test.qty Then

        rs.Edit
        rs!test.complete_line = True
        rs.Update
    End If
    End If
    'Move to the next record. 
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
 Else
 MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
 End If

 MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

 rs.Close 'Close the recordset
 Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up`
```

Comment: i would like to post a picture from the table with the data but i don't know how? i tried in several fields but i not allowed to post this?

Comment: Don't use images to provide data! See [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

You don't list the field, but it could be something like this:

```vb
If rs!SumOfav_stock > rs!test.qty Then
    rs.Edit
        rs!test.complete_line.Value = True
        rs!test.total.Value = rs!test.total.Value + DeliveredQuantity
    rs.Update
End If
```